# Upgrading Driver for Radeon RX 480

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and experiencing freezing that I believe is the graphics driver. I tried installing the [latest driver](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) from AMD's website but end up with this screen on reboot:

I tried previous driver versions as well with same result.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:303 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe83ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

[amdgpu startup fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erkWh.jpg)

Comment: You shouldn't use that driver with 17.10 and use open source driver instead.

Comment: Is the open source driver included with 17.10?